# Row Count Combined with Field in Group

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that is grouped by name so it is something like:

```
Justin
    Data 1     Data 2
Bob
    Data 1     Data 2
```

and I want to make it so it has the count of items in the group so like:

```
Justin (1)
    Data 1     Data 2
Bob (1)
    Data 1     Data 2
```

So I tried doing this: `=Fields!ownerid.Value + " " + Count(Fields!ownerid.Value)` But this just shows `#Error` with the following error: `Warning  1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘ownerid.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.`

But I don't really understand why this doesn't work, is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you need to explicitly convert the numeric value to its string equivalent. Try changing the expression to:

```
=Fields!ownerid.Value + " (" + CStr(Count(Fields!ownerid.Value)) + ")"
```

(Note that if `ownerid` is also a numeric - instead of a name, as in the example - then it too will need to be converted.)